# Notifications in a asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, notifications

We have several events that should trigger a notification to the user.
Everytime someone comments on their wall.
Everytime they win a trophy. 
Etc.

So notifications are stored in the database but not really related to any other model. just a html string, really.

Is there a recommended way to handling this other than the obvious "in your controller right after the creation of the comment or trophy or whatever create a notification as well" angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an ActionFilter to do that checking for you. ActionFilters are AOP-esque ways to do things before/after actions execute. The classical example is logging: Lets say you want to log before/after every action, but writing Log(); everywhere isn't very DRY. So you can create a logging actionfilter. See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) for a good example.

Comment: that sounds cool but could you give me a little snippet of an example on how to do something like that?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the rather sparse original response. No coffee yet.

Comment: If somebody else makes a comment on your wall, how can you use this method to alert the user? You are relying on the user to do something else on the site before they get the notification. Surely you want it to happen when they make the comment, a la facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different types of notification, one that the user triggers, and one that somebody else triggers.

If you want to have a real-time update when someone posts on your wall and you don't want the user to have to refresh to see the notification icon/message/whatever, then you have a few options.

The first option would be come kind of client side polling using AJAX. You can quite easily implement this and it's a well proven technique, but you have a bit of overhead with the constant polling back to the website to check for new notifications. There are other solutions which whilst don't explicitly use AJAX, work along the same kind of lines.

The other solution which I would advise you to have a look at would be the up and coming websockets protocol which is already implemented in a lot of browsers. This allows for real real-time notifications back to the client without constant polling. There are plenty of services such as [pusher](http://pusher.com/) that handle most of the hard work for you so you can easily implement the message using a simple call to a service and a script on the client.

Note: real-time = a short enough period of time where the information is still relevant

Comment: well my problem is mostly about the AOP way of creating the notification... for notifying the user I will use ajax. but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check SignalR jQuery library with ASP.NET backend.

[Here is a Scott Hanselman podcast](http://hanselminutes.com/291/damian-edwards-explains-the-realtime-web-for-aspnet-with-signalr) about it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will check it out and see if I can have the users know of the notification as soon as its created!.. my problem was mostly about how to handle the creation of them in a AOP way really... im still not clear on that but will try to do it with ActionFilters :)